# sum qty with different date SQL Server

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables,

table 1 is transaction table

```
+----------+-----------+---------+------------+-----+
| IDOutlet | IDProduct | TrxType |  TrxDate   | Qty |
+----------+-----------+---------+------------+-----+
|      101 | ASD11     |       2 | 11/11/2015 |  15 |
|      101 | ASD11     |       3 | 11/14/2015 |  -3 |
|      101 | ASD11     |       3 | 11/17/2015 |  -6 |
|      101 | ASD11     |       2 | 11/22/2015 |   7 |
|      101 | ASD11     |       3 | 11/26/2015 |  -2 |
|      101 | ASD11     |       2 | 12/3/2015  |   1 |
|      101 | ASD11     |       3 | 12/9/2015  |  -3 |
|      101 | ASD11     |       3 | 12/11/2015 |  -2 |
|      101 | ASD11     |       2 | 12/12/2015 |   5 |
|      101 | FFD34     |       2 | 11/11/2015 |   9 |
|      101 | FFD34     |       3 | 11/14/2015 |  -3 |
|      101 | FFD34     |       2 | 11/16/2015 |   3 |
|      101 | FFD34     |       3 | 11/19/2015 |  -4 |
|      101 | FFD34     |       3 | 11/23/2015 |  -3 |
|      102 | FFD34     |       2 | 11/26/2015 |   2 |
|      102 | FFD34     |       2 | 11/28/2015 |   4 |
|      102 | FFD34     |       3 | 11/29/2015 |  -5 |
|      102 | FFD34     |       3 | 12/1/2015  |  -1 |
+----------+-----------+---------+------------+-----+
```

Table 2 is opnametable

```
+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| IDOutlet | IDProduct | OpnameDate | QtyOpname |
+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|      101 | ASD11     | 11/20/2015 |         5 |
|      101 | FFD34     | 11/30/2015 |         5 |
|      102 | FFD34     | 11/30/2015 |         1 |
+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

And I want the result like this

```
+----------+-----------+------------+---------+
| IDOutlet | IDProduct | OpnameDate | Sum Qty |
+----------+-----------+------------+---------+
|      101 | ASD11     | 11/20/2015 |       6 |
|      101 | FFD34     | 11/20/2015 |       5 |
|      102 | FFD34     | 11/30/2015 |       1 |
+----------+-----------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: What's your question?  Table structure, sample data and expected results...

Comment: I removed the extra 'snippet' stuff, you don't need those, just clarify the question a bit, we see what you have, what do you want? What have you tried?

Comment: I need to sum the qty in the transaction table but the calculation refers to opname date

Comment: You need to JOIN transaction to opnametable

Comment: I can JOIN but my problem is the SUM qty should be stop until opnamedate, and I dont know how to do it

Comment: What do you mean by stop until opnamedate?

Comment: ex 101 ASD11 have trx between 11 nov - 12 dec, and the opname date is 20 nov. SO I need to calculate to sum the qty between 11 nov - 20 nov trx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a date comparison in your `JOIN` criteria:

```
SELECT  T2.IDOutlet,T2.IDProduct,T2.OpnameDate,SUM(T1.Qty) AS Sum_Qty
FROM opnametable T2
LEFT JOIN transaction T1
  ON T2.IDOUtlet = T1.IDOutlet
 AND T2.IDProduct = T1.IDProduct
 AND T1.TrxDate  <= T2.OpnameDate 
GROUP BY T2.IDOutlet,T2.IDProduct,T2.OpnameDate
```

I'm assuming the dates are stored in an appropriate date datatype, and that you want to include `OpnameDate`.

Comment: @shawnt00 I sure do, had initially misunderstood what they were after and was using a subquery, failed to switch it back.

Comment: sum(qty) is the sum of the quantity in the transaction table

Comment: @Hart I know how that goes.

Comment: @HartCO I have another question about this, what if one iDoutlet have several opname date. Can you help me ?

Comment: @Henry Might be worth opening a new question for that, I'm not sure if I follow exactly, but you'd need to either choose one of the dates if there are multiples, maybe `MAX()` in a subquery before joining, or you'll need to expand your criteria in some other way to not double-count any rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select o.IDOutlet,o.IDProduct,sum(t.Qty) as [Sum Qty]
from opnametable o left outer join transaction1 t on  o.IDOutlet=t.IDOutlet
and o.IDProduct=t.IDProduct and t.trxdate<o.OpnameDate
group by o.IDOutlet,o.IDProduct
```